# String interpolation in a shared library's global variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees, jenkins-shared-libraries

Cloudbees 2.289.1.2

I am changing the code as per the Jenkinsfile [string interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) guidelines.
Note: I am aware that Groovy String interpolation expects double-quotes for variables to be included.

There are several sh  in several global variables(under vars/) in a shared library.

Currently(without using String interpolation directives by Jenkins), the commands specified below give a warning(shown after each command).

**First command:**
This command can't populate custom/user-defined variables but ***it seems*** that username and password are populated:

```
String resultingImage = "${repo}/${parameters.openshiftProject}/${appImageName}"
                    .toLowerCase()
// tag images
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
                credentialsId: pushCredentialsId,
                passwordVariable: 'password',
                usernameVariable: 'username')]) {

    parameters[IMAGE_TAGS].each { tagName ->
        sh 'set +x skopeo copy docker://$resultingImage:latest docker://$resultingImage:$tagName --src-tls-verify=false --src-creds=$username:$password --dest-creds=$username:$password echo "done copying ${resultingImage}:${tagName}"'
              }
  }
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $username or $password
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x skopeo copy docker://:latest docker://: --src-tls-verify=false '--src-creds=****:****' '--dest-creds=****:****' echo 'done copying :'
```

If double-quotes are used, the following warning is shown but the command is formed correctly:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [password, username]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ set +x
```

**Second command:**
This throws an error(***seems that*** the credentials are retrieved correctly), no matter if I use "${chartTarballName}" or ${chartTarballName} or $chartTarballName:

```
sh 'curl -f -u $username:$password -T "${chartTarballName}" $chartPublishRepo/$chartTarballName'
```

The error:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -f -u ****:**** -T '' /
curl: (3) <url> malformed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: script returned exit code 3
```

If double-quotes are used, the following warning is shown but the command is formed correctly:

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [password, username]
See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ curl -f -u ****:**** -T exp-calculator-0.14.11.tgz https://repository.net/artifactory/stable-local/exp-calculator-0.14.11.tgz
```

I guess that these interpolation rules work only within a declarative pipeline directive, and not for scripted pipelines,  global variables(at least, the user-defined variables) in a shared library, and other Groovy DSL scripts.

Update-1:

The single-quote seems to work only for the standard, directive pipeline directives:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        CUSTOM_ENV_VAR = 'This is an environment variable'
    }
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sq_token', variable: 'SECRET')]) {
                    sh ("echo $SECRET")
                    sh ('echo $SECRET $CUSTOM_ENV_VAR')
                    
                    script {
                       String scriptBlockVariable = 'This is a variable in a script block'
                       sh ('echo $scriptBlockVariable')
                       sh ('echo $SECRET $scriptBlockVariable')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $SECRET
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [SECRET]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ echo ****
****
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo **** This is an environment variable
**** This is an environment variable
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo ****
****
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at it as follows: when you execute a job that uses interpreters such as the `sh`, `bat` and `powershell`, there are two separate contexts that hold parameters for the execution.
The first context is the actual groovy code that holds all parameters that where defined by the code, it could be input parameters, global parameters or any parameter that was defined in your code using the `def` keyword.
The second context is the set of parameters that will be loaded into the execution runtime environment whenever you run an interpreter step (`sh`, `bat`, `powershell`), this parameters will be available to these steps as environment parameters.

The [string interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) of groovy runs in the first context and can access only variables defined in the code, while commands that are passed and executed by the shell steps can access only parameters from the second context. In your case you are mixing both of them together.

Now let's examine the different keywords and their scope:
A simple `def` statement for defining a parameter will make it available for the **first context** - groovy code and thus string interpolation.
`parameters` block in the declarative pipeline is a special keyword that makes the parameters available in **both contexts** - it is available to the groovy code but is also loaded as an environment variables to the runtime environment of shell steps environment.It supports both regular parameters and credentials.
Scripted pipelines can't use the `parameters` directive, instead they have a different keyword for adding parameters to execution environment which is called [withEnv](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables):

> `withEnv` - Sets one or more environment variables within a block. These are available to any external processes spawned within that scope.

`withEnv` supports only regular parameters and therefore another keyword was introduced for supporting credentials: the [withCredentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#credentials-binding-plugin) that enables to set credentials parameters alike the `withEnv` step.

### Back to your problem:

Jenkins indeed [recommends](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables) not to use string interpolation for sensitive parameters, but rather pass them to the execution environment (**context 2**) and lets the shell steps use them as environment variables, so for that you need to define your string with single quotes, but on the other hand you want to use parameters defined in your code (**context 1**) which can be evaluated only with string interpolation that requires double quotes. So you are actually trying to use parameters from both context simultaneously which is a bit tricky.

You have two options for handling this mixture:

1 - use the `withCredentials` alongside the `withEnv` keyword, define the string with single quotes (disable string interpolation) using shell syntax parameter reference (`$`) and let the shell **extract all the parameters** from the environment variables. Something like:

```
String resultingImage = "${repo}/${parameters.openshiftProject}/${appImageName}".toLowerCase()
// tag images
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: pushCredentialsId, passwordVariable: 'password',usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
    parameters[IMAGE_TAGS].each { tagName ->
        withEnv(['TAG_NAME=tagName', "IMAGE=${resultingImage}"]) {
            sh 'set +x skopeo copy docker://$IMAGE:latest docker://$IMAGE:$TAG_NAME --src-tls-verify=false --src-creds=$username:$password --dest-creds=$username:$password echo "done copying $IMAGE:$TAG_NAME"'
        }
    }
}
```

2 - separate the creation of the command string into parts, each handling the correct context - groovy parameters will be evaluated when the command is created and the **only the relevant parameters** will be extract by the shell command. Something like:

```
String resultingImage = "${repo}/${parameters.openshiftProject}/${appImageName}".toLowerCase()
// tag images
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: pushCredentialsId, passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
    parameters[IMAGE_TAGS].each { tagName ->
        sh 'set +x skopeo copy docker://' + resultingImage + ':latest docker://' + "${resultingImage}:${tagName}" + '--src-tls-verify=false --src-creds=$username:$password --dest-creds=$username:$password echo' + /"done copying ${resultingImage}:${tagName}"/
    }
}
```

---

Here is a very [nice article](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/) on Jenkins environment variables and usage.

Comment: The primary concern here is security. Is 2. (concatenating sh command) a secure way or are env variables better?

Comment: As long as the credentials are not parsed in the code but only by the shell command then it is secure, so bot options are safe on that term. Option 1 is a bit more elegant for my taste and simulates the exact behavior of the `environment` step of the declarative pipeline.

Comment: It seems like your options at the bottom are no better, though, because of Injection via interpolation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation). You're using interpolation in `resultingImage`, then just injecting that variable into the environment using `withEnv()` or just using interpolation directly in the second one. Doesn't that run into the same injection-type attack possibilities, since `resultingImage` could contain malicious code and whatever you put into `resultingImage` will be passed into the shell?

Comment: @TylerCheek that is correct, but that can be said on any string that is passed to the shell. The idea is to prevent passing interpolated credentials and avoid the risk of the credentials being exposed.