# Handle string interpolation in shell command in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, string-interpolation, cloudbees, cicd

We have a pipeline where we need to invoke external API with `Authorization` header, whose value comes from Jenkins secret, which has been pre-configured.

When implemented as below, Jenkins complains for string interpolation.

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '<SECRETNAME>', variable: 'Token')]) { 
  sh """curl --location --request POST 'https://abc.example.com/api/endpoint' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${Token}' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw ${payload}""
```

We have tried will single quotes for `sh` and double quotes but nothing works out.
How it can be handled here?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins doesn't want you to interpolate passwords in the code but rather pass them as environment variables to the shell and let the shell command extract them, that is possible only for parameters that are loaded into the shell execution environment.
In declarative pipelines loading parameters and secrets into shell environment can be done using the `environment` directive and for scripted pipelines loading secrets can be done via the `withCredentials` keyword and loading regular parameters can be done via the 'withEnv` keyword.

In your case you have the `Token` parameter which is loaded into environment by the `withCredentials` step and the `payload` parameter which is probably not, so you are mixing two type of parameter contexts, more information on this is available in the [Answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752917/string-interpolation-in-a-shared-librarys-global-variable/68761032#68761032).

To solve it you have two options.
The first option is to load the payload into the environment of the shell and use a single quoted groovy string:

```groovy
withEnv(["PAYLOAD=${payload}"]) {
   withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '<SECRETNAME>', variable: 'Token')]) {
       sh '''curl --location --request POST "https://abc.example.com/api/endpoint" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer $Token" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-raw $PAYLOAD'''
   }
}
```

Second option is to separate the construction of the string into two types, and handle each section with the relevant method:

```groovy
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '<SECRETNAME>', variable: 'Token')]) {
   sh '''curl --location --request POST "https://abc.example.com/api/endpoint" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer $Token" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-raw ''' + payload
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I forgot to mention. I need to solve only for `Token` in this situation. I will give it a try.